# Trying to display Json response in HTML using JS

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to display json on web page and i'm using the following code but it doesn't work, who can help me understand what am i doing wrong?

```
<button type="submit" onclick="javascript:send()">call</button>

<div id="div"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function send()
{
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    //xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = callbackFunction(xmlhttp);
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://stam/1.1/json/url=https://www.google.co.il");
     xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlhttp.responseType = 'json';
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    //xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = callbackFunction(xmlhttp);
    var requestDoneAndOK = false;
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4) {
            if (xmlhttp.status === 200) {
                //requestDoneAndOK = true;  
                var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = xmlhttp.statusText + ":" + xmlhttp.status + "<BR><textarea rows='100' cols='100'>" + jsonResponse + "</textarea>";

            }               
        }
    };

}


</script>
```

Comment: your url `http://stam/1.1/json/url=https://www.google.co.il`  looks weird

Answer (score 0):

Your url is not correct. Also you should removed the commented out lines mentioned in the code to make it work.

You can use this dummy url to check if it's working: 
https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2

```
function send()
{
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    //xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = callbackFunction(xmlhttp);
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://stam/1.1/json/url=https://www.google.co.il");
     xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    xmlhttp.send();
  // Remove the below commented lines and change the url
  //     xmlhttp.responseType = 'json';
  //     xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  //     xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = callbackFunction(xmlhttp);
    var requestDoneAndOK = false;
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4) {
            if (xmlhttp.status === 200) {
                //requestDoneAndOK = true;  
                var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = xmlhttp.statusText + ":" + xmlhttp.status + "<BR><textarea rows='100' cols='100'>" + jsonResponse + "</textarea>";

            }               
        }
    };

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The URL you provided does not seem to work. Open the browser console (F12 and switch to the console tab). If you try `http://date.jsontest.com/`, for example, the browser console will log any errors.

For some reason, Firefox allowed me to make the request, but Chromium did not. Chromium's console provided the exact line numbers where there were issues.

1. I removed the second `xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");`.
2. It also told me that the response type in `xmlhttp.responseType = 'json';` should be `text`.

Here is the final product. Notice that I have to specify the key of the JSON object in order to get its value: `jsonResponse.time`

```
<button type="submit" onclick="javascript:send()">call</button>

<div id="div"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  function send() {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://date.jsontest.com/");
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlhttp.responseType = 'text';
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4) {
        if (xmlhttp.status === 200) {
          var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
          document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = xmlhttp.statusText + ":" + xmlhttp.status + "<br><textarea rows='100' cols='100'>" + jsonResponse.time + "</textarea>";
        }
      }
    };
  }
</script>
```

To print out the entire JSON object:

```
// var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText); No need for this.
document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = xmlhttp.statusText + ":" + xmlhttp.status + "<br><textarea rows='100' cols='100'>" + xmlhttp.responseText + "</textarea>";
```

Also, the concept of [unobtrusive JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) is worth taking a look at.